# In laravel how do I fetch date as date instead of datetime format?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my database some fields are set as date, while others are datetime or timestamp formats. However when fetching data, the "date" fields are also shown with the 00:00:00 time string attached at the end. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `date`/`datetime` casting with an additional format parameter as described in the [Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) documentation.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
    ];
}
```

This will apply the given format when serializing the model to an array or json. If you want to use a different format in your blade templates, you can use the `format()` function on the datetime property you want to change:

`{{ $user->created_at->format('Y-m-d') }}` or `{{ $user->created_at->toDateString() }}`

You will have to add the `created_at` column to the `$dates` property of your model though:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
];
```

This basically adds `'created_at' => 'datetime'` to your `$casts`.